# Different exception handling between Task.Run and Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library, taskfactory

I encountered an issue when I was using `Task.Factory.StartNew` and tried to capture an `exception` that is thrown. In my application I have a long running task that I want to encapsulate in a `Task.Factory.StartNew(.., TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);`

However, the exception isn't caught when I'm using `Task.Factory.StartNew`. It is however working as I expect when I use `Task.Run`, which I thought was just a wrapper on `Task.Factory.StartNew` (according to for instance [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173.aspx)).

A working example is provided here, the difference being that the exception is written to console when using `Task.Run`, but not when using `Factory.StartNew`.

**My question would be:**
if I have a `LongRunning` task that has the possibility to throw exceptions, how should I handle them in the calling code?

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task<bool> t = RunLongTask();
    t.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private async static Task<bool> RunLongTask()
{
    try
    {
        await RunTaskAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return false;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("success");
    return true;
}

private static Task RunTaskAsync()
{
    //return Task.Run(async () =>
    //    {
    //        throw new Exception("my exception");
    //    });
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(
        async () =>
    {
        throw new Exception("my exception");
    });

}
```

Comment: What happens if you do Task.Factory.StartNew(someAction, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default) - do you get the same result?

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, same result unfortunately

Comment: Also, see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx (one of the comments near the end asks a similar question)

Comment: @MatthewWatson I can't see which comment though.. The one from `nick` seems to only handle the difference between `await Task.Run(() => ..` and `await Task.Run(async () => ..`

Comment: Hmm yes, I was assuming the async thing was something to do with it. Perhaps it's not!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is that `StartNew` doesn't work like `Task.Run` with `async` delegates. The return type of `StartNew` is `Task<Task>` (which is convertible to `Task`). The "outer" `Task` represents the beginning of the method, and the "inner" `Task` represents the completion of the method (including any exceptions).

To get to the inner `Task`, you can use `Unwrap`. Or you can just use `Task.Run` instead of `StartNew` for `async` code. `LongRunning` is just an optimization hint and is really optional. [Stephen Toub has a good blog post on the difference between `StartNew` and `Run` and why `Run` is (usually) better for `async` code.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/)

**Update from @usr comment below:** `LongRunning` only applies to the beginning of the `async` method (up until the first incomplete operation is `await`ed). So it's almost certainly better all around to use `Task.Run` in this case.

Comment: At my work, we are however encouraged to use these optimization hints. Would it be better if I instead of converting it to a `async void` use a return value from the `Factory.StartNew` (is that even possible)?

Comment: To reduce confusion, I'd recommend making it a separate method. Also read Stephen Toub's blog post; if you use the older `StartNew` with the newer `async` code, you probably want to also call `Unwrap`.

Comment: My answer was incorrect; it wasn't a lambda conversion causing the issue. It was the wrapping of the `Task`. I've updated my answer to be... well... *right*. :)

Comment: @StephenCleary This is confusing, according to ReSharper, your previous answer was correct. But according to VS, your new answer is.

Comment: I encountered a new strange thing. `Unwrap` does solve the issue so that's great! However, the intellisense is complaining that the return value of `(async () => { .. }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Unwrap();` *cannot convert instance argument type 'Task' to 'Task<Task>'*. It compiles and runs fine though

Comment: @Default Are you using ReSharper?

Comment: LongRunning is identical to forcing a new thread to be created in practice. And your async method is probably not on that thread for a long time (it is taken off at the first await point). You don't *want* LongRunning in this case.

Comment: @svick - yes I am. Is it Re# that is complaining? It looked like an intellisense error

Comment: @Default Yeah, I think it is. I believe ReSharper overrides IntelliSense.

Comment: @usr this is only example code. The code we are working with does imply a long running operation, thus why we are using it.

Comment: @Default so your code will run for a long time until the *first* await point is hit? It does not matter how long the async method runs. The thread is destroyed at the very first await (that operates on a non-completed task).

Comment: @usr It do have the potential to. I might need to read more about this. Is `LongRunning` a suggestion only for the compiler? When running my application, will my Tasks be analyzed and be created in a new thread if needed? Could it be that I am preoptimizing this..?

Comment: @svick: I'd tend to believe VS. I've actually gotten out of the habit of using Re# since they didn't adopt `async` as quickly as my code did. :)  I don't have the knowledge to say *for sure* which one is right; I've asked Eric Lippert to do a blog post on the updated `async` method resolution rules. But I suppose I could stop being lazy and check out the updated language spec myself. :)

Comment: @usr: Excellent point about losing the `LongRunning` thread! I'll edit that into my answer.

Comment: @Default the compiler is generally unable to analyze your code in any major way. Also the compiler does not know anything about the TPL. The TPL is a library. And this library will just always launch a new thread. Specify LongRunning iff your task will almost always burn 100% CPU for multiple seconds or will block for multiple seconds with very high probability.

Comment: @usr thank you for your input. Would you mind adding your input as an "assistant answer" so that I can at least upvote it? I think it has high value in this thread.

Answer (score 2):

I'll pull some of my comments into an answer because they turned out to be helpful:

`LongRunning` is identical to forcing a new thread to be created in practice. And your async method is probably not on that thread for a long time (it is taken off at the first await point). You don't want LongRunning in this case.

It does not matter how long the async method runs. The thread is destroyed at the very first await (that operates on a non-completed task).

Can the compiler use this hint in any way? The compiler is generally unable to analyze your code in any major way. Also the compiler does not know anything about the TPL. The TPL is a library. And this library will just always launch a new thread. Specify `LongRunning` iff your task will almost always burn 100% CPU for multiple seconds or will block for multiple seconds with very high probability.

**My guess** is you don't want `LongRunning` here because if you're blocking, why are you using async in the first place? async is about not blocking but getting off the thread.

Comment: do you have any reference about the `LongRunning` being taken of at the first await point? I'd like to read more about it

Comment: @Default await queues a callback to be executed when the operation is complete. Having done that it always returns from the function. The TPL sees the return and ends the task (and the thread) (remember, there are two tasks here - see Stephen Cleary's answer. One (outer) task completes at the first await point and returns the inner task while the inner task completes at the end). See the blog series by Eric Lippert called "Asynchrony in C# 5". The language does not guarantee "being taken of at the first await point". This emerges from other behaviors kind of by coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible when you first [Unwrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap.aspx) the task:

```
await RunTaskAsync().Unwrap();
```

Or alternatively:

```
await await RunTaskAsync();
```